# openshift-django : syncdb, deploy script not running

Tags: python, django-models, openshift, django-syncdb

Is there any way by which I can run syncdb from my terminal? I don't know why my action_hooks/deploy script is not running. When I open my openshift database it show no table created.

```
source ${OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR}python-2.6/virtenv/bin/activate
export PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=${OPENSHIFT_HOME_DIR}python-2.6/virtenv/lib/python-2.6/site-packages
echo "Executing 'python ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIRwsgi/my/manage.py syncdb --noinput'"
python "$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR"my/manage.py syncdb --noinput
echo "Executing 'python ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}wsgi/my/manage.py collectstatic --noinput -v0'"
python "$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR"my/manage.py collectstatic --noinput -v0
```

git repo at https://github.com/sarvesh-onlyme/ninja/tree/master/openshift/django

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
source $OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/python-2.6/virtenv/bin/activate
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/wsgi/$OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME
python manage.py syncdb --noinput
```

Please make sure to do something similar if your application type is python 2.7 based.

let me know if it does not work.

Comment: There were some changes to action hooks, I hope you are following the latest set of instructions from here: https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/node/README.writing_applications.md#action-hooks. Also make sure you have execute permissions on the deploy script in your local git repo. For

Comment: mam, i'm new to this openshift thing, can u suggest me what's wrong in my openshift project, i've make a repo at https://github.com/sarvesh-onlyme/ninja/tree/master/openshift/django . could be pls suggest what wrong in there

Answer (score 0):

check logs (`rhc tail app_name`). Try to login to OpenShift app through ssh (`rhc ssh app_name`) and try to run deploy script manually (`cd app-root/runtime/repo/.openshift/action_hooks; ./deploy`). Do you see any errors?

Post your logs/errors here. I will update my answer afterwards.

//lol,  sorry, I did not notice it's two year old question.